# Launch Forms App when browse file clicked in webpage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**EDIT:** I am gong to rephrase the question, how can I make my Xamarin Forms app show up in the list of available apps when the user clicks on a browse button in a webpage, such as images.google.com, or Facebook (post or comment)?
I seem to have the general idea right, I know I need an intent to do it, but I cannot find the action or category combination that produces the correct result. Please assist.

I have a Xamarin Forms app that has 3 sections, the default Launcher which opens when you click on the app icon, which works perfectly, then I have an image manager section that launches from this intent...

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = false, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/LaunchTheme",
         ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
    },
    DataScheme = "file",
    DataMimeType = "*/*",
    DataPathPattern = ".*\\.jpg"

)]
```

Once the image has been edited it can be saved to a library within the app (this is actually a SQL database backed by Azure storage). 
Now what I would like to do is have the third section, a library of all managed images, be in the options when you click on a browse for file button in a webpage. Currently my device shows Gallery, and Prime Photos as options, what should the intent look like to enable this to happen?

[image: When this browse button is clicked, I want my app to be in the list of handlers]

Thanks
Shaine.

EDIT:
At this point I am aware that I need to make the IntentFilter into Intent.ActionGetContent, something like...

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = false, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/LaunchTheme",
     ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(
new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[]
{
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
    Intet.CategoryOpenable
},
DataScheme = "file",
DataMimeType = "image/*"
)]
```

However, I am not sure what the next step is, and the Xamarin docs on this are rare, if they even exist. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this : Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");intent.startActivity(intent);

Comment: @YorkShen, sadly no. You would think this would be easier. All I want to do is have an Activity launch as a gallery, I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The app is available as a resource to open images with, that works perfectly, but as for presenting itself as a gallery app, nowhere near. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...

```
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.ActionPick, Intent.ActionGetContent }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryOpenable }, DataMimeType = @"image/*")]
```

Thanks